# Upgrade Windows Server 2016 Standard to 2019 Datacenter

Tags: upgrade, windows-server-2016

I am trying to upgrade Windows Server 2016 Standard to 2019 Datacenter. As per what I google, I understood that this is not possible. The way to do it is first to upgrade to Windows Server 2019 Standard and then to convert it to Windows Server 2019 Datacenter.
The issue I am facing is when I am trying the first step to upgrade Windows Server 2016 standard to Windows Server 2019 Standard, Keep personal Files is greyed out.
Suggestion found in Google was to set UI language to the default. I have done it but I am still getting the Keep personal Files greyed out.
I am trying to install the same default language.
I there any experience and solution to anyone how to fix this greyed out issue?

Comment: We will have to know more about your configuration.  Are you trying to install the same language version of Windows Server 2019 that of the language version of Windows Server 2016?

Comment: @Ramhound, yes I am